# BI Publisher Web Service Token expire time

Tags: web-services, token, bi-publisher

I'm working on BI Publisher web service.

first, I call the login() with user name and password to get the TOKEN;
then, I call other insession methods with the TOKEN

My question is:
By default, how long the TOKEN will expire? This is a configuration in BI Publisher?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called web.xml somewhere in your BI Publisher install tree.  Per the [Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/entry/session_timeouts), it's found at:

> \applications\xmlpserver\xmlpserver\WEB-INF\web.xml

However, on my BI Publisher Trial Edition installation, it's found at:

> \bip\server\wls\user_projects\applications\bipdomain\xmlpserver\WEB-INF\web.xml

Thus, you may need to do a bit of searching to find it.  Wherever it is, you want to find this tag combination:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The value of session-timeout is measured in minutes.